# How to apply shadow, rounded corners, image and gaussian blur?

Tags: swift, user-interface

**What I need:**

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

**Here is my current code:**

```
class SchedulerSummaryCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var oneMileV: UIView! {
      didSet {
        oneMileV.backgroundColor = .clear
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        oneMileV.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)
        makeCircular(oneMileV)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            blurView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneMileV.heightAnchor),
            blurView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneMileV.widthAnchor),
            blurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneMileV.leadingAnchor),
            blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneMileV.topAnchor)
            ])
        oneMileV.layer.applySketchShadow(alpha: 0.5, y: 4, blur: 10)

    }
  }
}
```

**(HELPER)**

```
extension CALayer {
  func applySketchShadow(
    color: UIColor = .black,
    alpha: Float = 0.16,
    x: CGFloat = 0,
    y: CGFloat = 3,
    blur: CGFloat = 6,
    spread: CGFloat = 0)
 {
    masksToBounds = false
    shadowColor = color.cgColor
    shadowOpacity = alpha
    shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
    shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
    if spread == -1 {return}
    if spread == 0 {
        shadowPath = nil
    } else {
        let dx = -spread
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
        shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
    }
  }
}
```

**When I comment out the `applySketchShadow` code, I get this:**

[image]

---

**Questions**

Why does the gaussian blur cancel out the rounded corners?

Is there a way for me to apply both rounded corners and gaussian blur?

How should I then add an image?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your `UIImageView` as a subview to a `UIView`. The `UIView` will be responsible for the shadow and the `UIImageView` is going to take care of the rounded corners. Unfortunately you cannot add a shadow directly to the `UIImageView` because you need to enable `clipsToBounds = true` which prevents the view to show content outside of its bounds. This however is necessary for the shadow to be shown.

This will do the work:

```
let shadowView = UIView()
shadowView.backgroundColor = .clear
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 1)
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.14
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YourImage")
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2
shadowView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: This is a way to add a shadow, so its a nice contribution, but the challenge I'm facing is combining multiple layer manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

For shadow effect use this extention it will help you.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func addShadow() {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 5)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        self.clipsToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a way to add a shadow, so its a nice contribution, but the challenge I'm facing is combining multiple layer manipulations.